# Requirements for distributing android app privately to selected clients

Tags: android, share

I have a Google Play Console developer account and want to distribute an app to specific companies/clients privately.
What I'm not 100% sure about is what type of Google Play account the clients need, as I need to collect their organization IDs. Do they also need to set up a Developer Account so I can share the app privately with them?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to distribute your app to either an internal (max 100 users, email address) or closed (max 2000 users, email address or Google Group) channel. You probably want closed, although I'm not sure what you mean by organization IDs, maybe emails?

The user just needs a regular Google account email address (e.g. Gmail, or a Google Workplace domain) for both of these, and [the process is relatively simple](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334):

> **Create an email list of your testers**
>
> If you've already created your testers list, skip to the 'Add testers'
> instructions.
>
> 1. Open Play Console and go to the [Closed testing](https://play.google.com/console/developers/app/closed-testing)
>    page (**Testing > Closed testing**).
> 2. Select **Manage track**.
> 3. Select the **Testers** tab.
> 4. Under 'Testers', select **Create email list**.
> 5. Enter a list name. You can use the same list for future tests on any of your apps.
> 6. Add email addresses separated by commas or click **Upload CSV file**. If you use a .CSV 7. file, put each email address on its own line
>    without any commas. **Note:** If you upload a .CSV file, it will
>    overwrite any email addresses that you've added.
> 7. Select **Save changes**, then **Create**.
>
> **Add testers**
>
> 1. Open Play Console and go to the [Closed testing](https://play.google.com/console/developers/app/closed-testing)
>    page (**Testing > Closed testing**).
> 2. Select Manage track.
> 3. Select the Testers tab.
> 4. In the 'Testers' section, you can add testers via email or Google Groups:
>
> - **Email: Email** is selected automatically. If you want to
>   use email, just select the user lists that you want to test your
>   release.
> - **Google Groups**: Select **Google Groups** and enter the
>   Google Group email addresses, which use the format:
>   yourgroupname@googlegroups.com. Only users who are members of the
>   Google Groups that you enter will be able to join your test.
>
>   - **Tip**: To learn how to manage Google Groups, go to the [G Suite Administrator Help
>     Centre](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085).
>
> 5. Provide a feedback URL or email address to collect feedback from testers. Your app's feedback channel will be shown to users on your
>    tester opt-in page.
> 6. Copy the shareable link to share the release with testers.
> 7. Select Save **changes**.

Alternatively, if you want to distribute the app to a company / client frequently (e.g. multiple times per day) with no processing delays etc, you may want to use [Internal App Sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679?hl=en-GB). This is slightly more complicated, but may suit your use case better.